# Multiple columns:Gridview

Tags: python, gridview, widget, tkinter

While using gridview in Tkinter can a widget occupy multiple columns?

I have read about `columnspan` but it is not working. My code is given below:

```
w = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
w.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

So what do I do?

Comment: not your answer: you can use `ipadx` & `ipady` . its working great for `columnspan` but not for `rowspan`

Comment: Works fine for me. What is making you think that it is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: & why your columnspan might not be working because if you are using only 1 column throughout your layout,then even using columnspan won't help. it will work only when you have used column 2 somewhere too(atleast that was the case for me)

Comment: @ebarr yes I have defined gridview and have used 2 columns above this (i.e. row=0). The problem is when I move to row 1 I cannot get this bar to span both the columns at the same time.

Comment: I'll post an answer, as I can't post code into the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a very minimal example of how columnspan works:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
w.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
tk.Label(root,text="column 0").grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Label(root,text="column 1").grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This will give:

[image: Example Tk output with Scale spanning 2 columns]

Answer (score 0):

To fill horizontally, use sticky="ew" (east to west).  To fill vertically, rows, use sticky="ns" (north to south).  Note in the following code the scale completely fills both columns, although it is a slight difference in this particular case.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
##w.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
w.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky="ew")
tk.Label(root,text="column 0").grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Label(root,text="column 1").grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```